# Setting Expires Headers for Things Retrieved Via Query String

Tags: .htaccess

I have an installation of MediaWiki and have been optimizing various aspects using Google's PageSpeed tool as a guide, and I've so far been able to make lots of improvements.

One thing I'm *not* able to do yet is set an Expires Header using my .htaccess file for the following resource:

```
http://example.com/mywiki/load.php?debug=false&lang=en-gb&modules=startup&only=scripts&skin=vector&*
```

It doesn't have a normal file extension like .css or .js.

*Can* I set Expires Headers in my .htaccess file for these sorts of files?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** probably it's not a good idea to set Expire Header for these resources.

**Explanation:**

You need to know more about the basics of URL format and its delimiters `://`, `@`, `:`, `?` and `#`:

```
scheme://[user:password@]domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id
```

In your URL:

- Scheme: `http`
- Username and password not present.
- Domain: `example.com`
- Port not present, defaults to HTTP port `80`
- **Path**: `/mywiki/load.php`
- **Query string**: `debug=false&lang=en-gb&modules=startup&only=scripts&skin=vector&*`
- Fragment ID not present.

The main problem here is that you are mixing the path and query string with each other. Your file location is `/mywiki/load.php` and it has normal file extension, `.php`. The query string on it's part sends data for this PHP script to process: name/value pairs separated by ampersands.

Now that we know we are dealing with a PHP script, we must realize that Apache is now providing **dynamic content**: content that changes. It is not generally a good idea to set cache control for this kind of content. If we would like to do that it is possible. We could set it by the file extension in `.htaccess` or the PHP script itself is also able to set cache headers, e.g.

```
header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 3600) . " GMT");
```

That would be an option if the PHP script provides images, downloads or other static content. However, since you are just using a PHP software instead of developing it, you should think that the programmers already have thought of that. It would also change back on updates.  Therefore, you are likely done with the cache control when you have set the headers for static content.

Comment: The actual content being delivered is minified javascript that, in practice, is not changing. In fact, it's being dragged out of a file cache that Mediawiki manages. The current expiry time is 5 minutes. I'd simply like to be able to extend this to an hour or more.

Comment: Then, you would probably like to add that `header()` command in the beginning of THAT .php file, not adjust cache headers for all php files. Just modify the `+ 3600` to meet your needs.

Comment: If that means modifying my MediaWiki installation, then I probably won't do that. If I do an update of MediaWiki, my changes will likely be lost. Thanks for answering!